# How to find phase sequence in 3 phase system using micro controller without zero cross over?

Tags: three-phase

I have 3 ADCs which are connected to 3 phases respectively. I have to find the phase sequence when it comes in picture...
I'm getting an ADC value for particular phase, but how can I find the sequence using microcontroller? The phases are directly connected with a resistor drop to micro controller.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is to send two phases (scaled, of course) to a flip flop- one phase goes to the D input and the other phase goes to the clock input. (No third phase input is required.)

If the phase goes, say ABC, the clock going high will always occur first relative to the D input going high, so a LOW will be clocked in (since D is still LOW), and the flipflop output will always be LOW for ABC rotation.

If the rotation is ACB, the D input going HIGH will occur first, and then the clock will go HIGH, causing the flop to clock in a HIGH on the output, signifying ACB rotation.

Go look at a graph of a 3-phase waveform. You'll be able to see the timing for when two adjacent phases are >0V, which correspond to the times when the above clocking occurs. You should be able to implement a digital comparator based on your read-in ADC values that can determine the sequence based on sequential peaks or numeric threshold crosses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little digital signal processing.
*With signed numbers, the ADC results must be converted first.*

First you have to use a DC offset removal filter. Sounds complicated, but isn't.
This can be as simple as a high pass filter.
Which in turn can be a simple as one or more passes trough an exponential weighted average [low pass](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/20342/38558) filter, where you subtract the result with what you put in.

Why this DC offset removal filter? The alternative is a hard coded 0 Volt threshold which may or may not be accurate in varying situations of mains distortion.

Convert these resulting waveforms to a square wave by a comparison with [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). 
Then you have your zero crossings! Store the sample timestamps of these crossings.

Take the rising edge of phase A and look for the following other two rising edges.

Whichever is first tells you if the phase sequence is cw or ccw.